# Is breaking TOS (Terms of Service) an aveira?

Tags: halacha, internet, legal-documents

I had a discussion with my friend yesterday about whether or not you can use a VPN according to Netflix TOS. The conclusion was that you can but it brought up another question, which is *“do you have an obligation to go through the TOS (Terms of Service) on every service you use in order to check that you aren’t breaking it and by breaking it, may be doing an aveira?”*

Comment: Related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/92994/6592

Comment: Closely related (possible duplicate?): https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13577/ https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/36924/ and https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/37913/

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Yehuda and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: I wouldn't feel comfortable doing it. These programs spend lots of money trying to catch people doing this specifically. You are paying to watch a certain selection, now you are accessing media that is not included in that contract at all and you know it. I can't see how it's more permissible than any other form of digital piracy.